# Understanding Index-Only Scan Behavior with JSONB Columns in PostgreSQL 13

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, jsonb, vacuum

I have a query involving a JSONB column in PostgreSQL, structured as follows:

```sql
select ((option ->> 'fruit_id'))
from table1 t1 
where ((option ->> 'fruit_id')) = '1'
limit 10
```

This query is designed to fetch data from a JSONB column named option, extracting the value associated with the key 'fruit_id'.

I have created a B-tree index on the expression (option ->> 'fruit_id') to optimize this query.
According to the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html), this setup seems to be a suitable candidate for an index-only scan.

However, the query appears to be using the index(`index scan`) but not performing an index-only scan. What could be the reason for this behavior? Is there something specific about JSONB indexing in PostgreSQL that prevents an index-only scan in this scenario?

I applied the `vacuum` command to the table, but even after that, index-only-scan was not performed.

### Referenced document content

- `The index type must support index-only scans. B-tree indexes always do`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same docs you referenced:

> In principle, index-only scans can be used with expression indexes.
> For example, given an index on f(x) where x is a table column, it
> should be possible to execute SELECT f(x) FROM tab WHERE f(x) < 1; as an index-only scan; and this
> is very attractive if f() is an expensive-to-compute function.
> However, PostgreSQL's planner is currently not very smart about such
> cases.  It considers a query to be potentially executable by index-only scan only when all **columns** needed by the query are available from the index. In this example, x is not needed except in the context f(x), but the planner does not notice that and concludes that an index-only scan is not possible.

You are using an operator, not a function, but that makes no difference to the planner, it is still an expression.

Comment: If you check the execution plan of the query, you can see that it is running on the index I created. It's just not index-only-scan.
So, why is it possible to use columns containing operators in index-scan, but not in index-only-scan?

Comment: Because no one has written the code to make that happen.